# What is the difference between rxkotlin and LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, rx-kotlin

I am learning Rx and I do not understand the difference between the two. Can you explain briefly?

Answer (score 0):

Rxkotlin -
RxKotlin is a lightweight library that adds convenient extension functions to RxJava. You can use RxJava with Kotlin out-of-the-box, but Kotlin has language features (such as extension functions) that can streamline usage of RxJava even more. RxKotlin aims to conservatively collect these conveniences in one centralized library, and standardize conventions for using RxJava with Kotlin.

Livedata -
LiveData is an observable data holder class. Unlike a regular observable, LiveData is lifecycle-aware, meaning it respects the lifecycle of other app components, such as activities, fragments, or services. This awareness ensures LiveData only updates app component observers that are in an active lifecycle stat